# Newspaper confusion and statistics.

Tags: statistics, bayes-theorem

As part of my new university course I am taking I need to do some statistics so I decided to do some practice. As I said I am new to statistics and I am currently very stuck on the following question:

[image]

And so far I have handled the question like this but I am not sure if I am doing it properly..

i)

Mon - ($150+140+110=400$)

Tue – ($70+80+65=215$)

Wed – ($20+18+21=59$)

Thu – ($25+22+16=63$)

Fri - ($35+30+35=100$)

$$\text{Total} = 400+215+59+63+100 = 837$$
$$p(Mon) = 400/837 = 0.47\%$$

ii)

$$\text{Ananova}/\text{Tuesday} = 70/(70+80+65)=70/215= 0.32%$$

iii)

No clue.

iv)

Didn't get to it. But cant really think of a way how to distribute the values using Bayes law.

The questions a bit weird but it would be lovely if someone can help me out on this issue.

Comment: Question (ii) is a bit ambiguously worded. Your answer is right if the want the probability that any of the Tuesday customers buys Ananova. It is wrong if they want the probability that any of the 837 customers buys Ananova on Tuesday.

Comment: Question (iii) has incomplete information. What is the probability that a customer does buy a second newspaper? Which probabilities are equal? Are the sales numbers still important? How many customers are there? You should just skip that question, it's trash.

Comment: This question was used in last years entry examination so it should be valid. I know it does look like absolute rubbish but I need to come up with some sort of a solution as it has pretty high chances of having exactly the same question but with different numbers given instead.